# How to reverse the `nbconvert --from python`?

Tags: emacs, ipython, org-mode, jupyter-notebook

Essentially I want to do the reverse of

```
ipython nbconvert --to python foo.ipynb
```

IOW, I want to programmatically "synthesize" iPython notebooks from Python source code<sup>1</sup> (possibly suitably commented).

Are there any tools to do this?

FWIW, I'm a veteran Emacs user, and a recent "convert" to its `org-mode`, so I particularly welcome solutions that work well with them.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Why I want to do this?  That's a very long and tedious story, but in brief: I have to turn in homeworks for a class as *.ipynb files, but I don't like working with iPython notebooks, since I'm a mouse-phobic, text-only Emacs-head.  The tools for working with iPython notebooks in Emacs are IMHO awful, if they work at all (this is actually the "long and tedious" part of the story).  The only remaining course of action for me is the one this post is about.</sup>

Comment: Now that's a first-world problem :). I guess the problem is that notebooks contain more information than just code. Converting `ipynb`->`py` is no problem, because you will lose information. Converting `py`->`ipynb` needs additional information... That said: Notebooks are just `json` files. Of course you can create your own notebooks and the run them via command line e.g with `runipy`. Easier would be: Write your code in your favorite editor and copy the results to a notebook before submitting your homework :)

Comment: @cel Indeed, it is first-world problem: I have RSI from mouse use; have needed surgery for both shoulders; my hatred of using the mouse has a medical basis.  (Then again, I can't think of any problem posted in SO that is *not* a first-world problem.)  Regarding your copy-paste suggestion: each homework entails filling 20-30 blanks with code.  That's 20-30 copy-paste operations.  No thanks.  But thanks for the runipy pointer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. IPython notebooks were not designed to be edited via command line. But as I said, of course noone stops you from learning the structure of the `json` files and manipulate the notebook with emacs. So in principle, it is possible to write and edit notebooks without ever using a gui. Of course it is not a very pleasant solution. But I doubt there's a better solution for this rather unusual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Dragging a py file onto the dashboard should do the trick (on 2.x version), there are some special comment markers that will split the notebook on the right place. It should be programmatically doable by importing `IPython.nbformat` that get all the python api to create notebooks. Some code is probably somewhere in `IPython/html/` if you want to go this route and have an example, feel free to ask on IPython-dev ml, we'll be happy to help you. This part of the code is not well user-tested.

You should have a look a [ipymd (ipynb+md)](https://github.com/rossant/ipymd). Cyrille is writing a book with it, and was dealing with more or less the same issue as "need to manipulate pure text".

I will also underline [EIN](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook) , but the de-facto maintained fork will be the one of [millejoh](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) which is regularly updated. You will be able to directly edit ipynb file from emacs, + inline graph etc... But I guess this is one of the "tools for working with iPython notebooks in Emacs" you don't like, but future reader might be interested.

Finally I just want to point out that if the assignment are as IPython notebook (type "fill in the blanks") and are made to be graded with something like [github:jupyter/nbgrader](https://github.com/jupyter/nbgrader) then going through pure-text might not work as ipynb might have extra metadata that wont survive the conversion.